# getBondedDevices() is not returning paired bluetooth devices

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to fetch paired devices using `BluetoothAdapter` like below.

```
fun getBondedDevices(){                                                             
 if (!checkBluetoothPermission(mContext) && !isBluetoothEnabled) 
   {
       return
   }

 val bondedDevice = mBluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices

}

fun checkBluetoothPermission(context: Context): Boolean {
    return if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S
    } else {
        true
    }
}
```

Using this code I am able to get paired devices but only for below device I am not able to get paired device which is already there in paired device list when I check in Bluetooth settings.

Android OS: 13,
Android API level: 33,
Device manufacturer: samsung,
Device model: SM-G998U

Can you please help me to understand why this Samsung device is not giving me paired device in list which is already paired, Is there any cache issue that can affect to retry list?

Help would be appreciated.